# Is DataTable passed by reference?

Tags: c#, .net

This might sound like a stupid question, but I just happened to stumbled upon this. I know you can use `ref` to pass a parameter by reference. But I have this method

```
    public void SaveRecordsIntoTemporaryTable(DataTable objDataTable, string userSessionID)
   {

       // The objDataTable has 5 columns "Id", "Name", "Tag_1", "Tag_2", "Tag_3"
       // Now in here I remove "Tag_1", "Tag_2", and "Tag_3"
       objDataTable.Columns.Remove("Tag_1");
       objDataTable.Columns.Remove("Tag_2");
       objDataTable.Columns.Remove("Tag_3");

       ...

   }
```

Now I have set a debug point on third line, but after I remove this column `"Tag_3"`, and I hover my cursor over `objDataTable` in the parameter, the `DataTable` it shows also has the columns removed? So, is it getting passed by reference?

**UPDATE**

Okay, if it is getting passed by `reference`, what difference would it make if I use `ref`?

Comment: its because `DataTable` is a reference type.

Comment: @Razort4x, With reference to your edit: it is **not** passed by reference. But when you use `ref` keyword, then you can modify the orignal reference like setting it to null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, is it getting passed by reference?

Its address is passed by value. Since `DataTable` is a class *(a reference type)*, Its address gets passed by value and hence you see the change.

Try doing:

```
objDataTable = null;
```

If it is truly passed by reference then you will see the caller setting the `DataTable` to `null` but **that doesn't happen**.

See: [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score -1):

`DataTable`, and anything else derived from object is passed by reference.  If you were to explicitly pass it as `ref`, then the reference would be by reference - allowing you to change the variable to point to another `DataSet` (or null).

**Edit** - ignore the first sentence.  It should be `DataTable` and anything else derived from `object` is a reference type.

Calling a method passing a reference type by value still allows modifying the properties of the type.

Comment: No, it is not passed by reference.  It *is* a reference, and it is passed by value.  This is a very important distinction.

Comment: Re-read what I said.  *If* he were to pass by reference with `ref`, then it would be a reference to a reference.  The existing code does pass a reference by values as you state.

Comment: It seems you have the correct understanding of what happens. However, it is incorrect to say "_... is passed by reference_". Pass-by-reference semantics is well-defined and it is not what happens here.

Comment: @DavidCrowell Your first sentance, `DataTable, and anything else derived from object is passed by reference.` is wrong.  Your second sentence is not wrong, but your first is.